# How Can I Make URLs Clickable in a Table Column in DataGrip?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I'm working with DataGrip by JetBrains and have a table column filled with URLs. Currently, to open these URLs, I have to copy and paste them into a web browser manually, which is quite tedious. I'm seeking a way to make these URLs directly clickable from within DataGrip, allowing them to open in a browser with a simple click.

Does anyone know if DataGrip supports this feature, or is there a workaround to achieve clickable URLs within its interface? I'm looking for any method, plugin, or setting adjustment that would allow for this functionality.

I appreciate any guidance or tips you can offer on this matter. Thank you!

I've conducted several internet searches in an attempt to find a solution to this issue but unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any relevant information or guidance on making URLs clickable in DataGrip. I was hoping there might be a straightforward setting or a plugin that could enable this functionality, but so far, I haven't come across anything that addresses this specific need.

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains [says it currently cannot be done](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006514120-How-to-make-urls-in-Table-View-clickable), but there is [an open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-14892/Allow-quick-navigation-by-recognised-URL-in-DB-table-view) for it.